# Ant script to find a file in a path and add the full path to a property

Tags: ant

I have a need to find a file in a path from ant. Essentially I have a standard path style variable like DIR1:DIR2 and I need to locate a file called foo in that path and put the full path of it in a variable.

Is that possible to do with Ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task with a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) element.

For example:

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <path id="files.path">
        <fileset dir="dir1"/>
        <fileset dir="dir2"/>
    </path>

    <target name="run">
        <pathconvert property="path.output" refid="files.path">
            <globmapper from="*foo.jar" to="*foo.jar"/>
        </pathconvert>

        <echo message="Output: ${path.output}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

## Test

ANT project with the following files:

```
$ tree
.
|-- build.xml
|-- dir1
|   `-- subdir1
|       `-- foo.jar
`-- dir2
    `-- nogood.jar

3 directories, 3 files
```

### Running example

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /home/me/build.xml

run:
     [echo] Output: /home/me/dir1/subdir1/foo.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Is there any way to put this into a variable though?

Comment: @DeanPovey I've included the test in my answer, in case the solution requires clarification. You wanted the file found to be put into a property? In this case it's "path.output"